# How many different robots were sent back in time in the entire Terminator franchise?

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator-series

How many different robots (physical units, NOT model types) were sent back in time in the entire Terminator franchise?

The count should encompass ALL franchise works, not just the movies.

While I'm most interested in the final count, if you can please post either a list netting to that count, or a link to external source with such a list. This is so that the answer can be adjusted in the future if the franchise adds more works.

<sub>NOTE: I'm not aware if such a situation ever arose, but if it did, the same robot's physical body sent back >1 time only counts once. This includes even if it was sent again after being completely re-programmed from original traveled program.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I did decide to post this after seeing META Rondo question. But this bugged me for a long time ever since reading one of overthinkingit.com Terminator articles.

Comment: If I flag this as a "time traveling robot question" will it go down as a good flag or a bad one?

Comment: And then what happens when/if terminator 5 is released, where we have more robots sent back in time. The assumptions make the question localized in time. Do you mean to ask in the original trilogy? What are you considering to be in the 'franchise'?

Comment: So tempted to append "On a similar note..." to this question.

Comment: @NominSim - I double-dog-dare you...

Comment: @JohnO - I am not a moderator so take this with a grain of salt, but my understanding is that the flag being good or bad basically correlates with whether moderator's judgement of the post agree with your flagging intent. I've had some 100% factually correct flags rejected as unhelpful

Comment: Regretably, unlike the 40W Plasma Rifle, the franchise canon doesn't have a laser sight. Times changed. Things happened. Records were lost.

Comment: @Pureferret - All movies, TV series, books, computer games or comics/graphics novels or other content that are officially licensed to use the franchise settings. Basically, the legal franchise. As far as T5, that is why "Edit" was invened on SE and why I asked for actual list that the count is based on as supplement.

Comment: @Pureferret - Unless he qualifies it otherwise, franchise is well-defined to mean the movie, its sequels, and the television show. Comic books as well. Excluding all fan fiction.

Comment: @DVK I'd still argue it's localized.

Comment: @Pureferret - you have a point, but on that basis, you can argue that nearly 100% of SFF's Harry Potter questions are localized since JKR keeps coming up with new content in both interviews and PotterMore and future Encyclopedia. Ditto for all of Star Wars questions since Lucas can release canon-changing movie revisions at any time in the future. <sub>Han negotaited nicely with Greedo till he fell asleep</sub>. You're welcome to VTC as localized though, it's your full right :)

Comment: @DVK I said I'd argue, not that I was convinced. Every question deserves a chance.

Comment: @Pureferret - may be worth a meta Q?

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11201/4707) is good as well I think

Comment: Should Cromartie's chassis count once or twice?  Since John Henry was created in the modern day and used his chassis, but only when _forward_ in time...

Answer (score 18):

TLDR; My final count is **34**

- **18** for the 4 Movies and Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles
- **16** in Novels and Comics.

I hope I didn't forgot any :

---

- Movies : 5

  - [Terminator (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/)  : 1

    1. [T-800 (The Terminator)](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-800_%28The_Terminator%29)
  - [Terminator 2: Judgment Day (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/) : 2

    1. [T-800 (Uncle Bob)](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-800_%28Terminator_2%29)
    2. [T-1000](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-1000_%28character%29)
  - [Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181852/) : 2

    1. [T-850](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-850_%28character%29)
    2. [T-X](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_T-X)
  - [Terminator Salvation (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0438488/) : 0

    - none
- [Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles (2008–2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0851851/) : 13

  - Season 1 : 4

    1. [Cameron](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron)
    2. [Cromartie](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cromartie)
    3. [Vick](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Vick_Chamberlain) (termination of the Resistance fighter)
    4. [Carter](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Carter) (securing a shipment of coltan in Depot 37)
  - Season 2 : 9

    1. [Catherine Weaver](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Catherine_Weaver)
    2. [Carl Greenway's replacement](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Carl_Greenway_%28T-888%29) (Serrano Point Nuclear Power Plant incident)
    3. [James Ellison's flailed replacement](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/James_Ellison_%28Terminator%29)
    4. [Myron Stark](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Myron_Stark) (ended up in 1920)
    5. [The one who tried to kill Bedell](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bedell_Terminator)
    6. [Water Delivery Guy](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Water_Delivery_Guy)
    7. [Rosie](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Rosie) (the red-headed contortionist Terminator)
    8. [The one who tried to kill the Fields family](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fields_Terminator)
    9. The former owner of the endoskeleton hand involved in a plane crash in 2002. ([Catherine Weaver showed photographic evidence of this hand to Ellison when she was recruiting him](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_203%3a_The_Mousetrap))

---

The section on Novels and Comics is based on [Terminator.wikia Time travel article, Missions section](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Time_travel#Missions). This might be improved because my knowledge of those is limited.

- Novels : 1

  - [T2: Infiltrator](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T2%3a_Infiltrator) : 1

    1. [Serena Burns](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Serena_Burns)
- Comics : 15

  - [The Terminator: One Shot](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_One_Shot) : 1

    1. [The Amazon](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Amazon)
  - [The Terminator: Death Valley](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_Death_Valley) : 2

    1. [D810.X](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/D810.X)
    2. [D800.L](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/D800.L)
  - [The Terminator: The Dark Years](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_The_Dark_Years) : 1

    1. an unspecified Terminator
  - [The Terminator: Tempest](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_Tempest) : 4

    1. [Dudley aka I825.M](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Dudley)
    2. [C890.L](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/C890.L)
    3. [C850.D](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/C850.D)
    4. [HC875.S](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/HC875.S)
  - [The_Terminator: Secondary Objectives](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_Secondary_Objectives) and [The Terminator: End Game](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator%3a_End_Game) : 2

    1. [Z000.M](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Z000.M)
    2. [The Machine](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Machine)
  - [Painkiller Jane vs. Terminator](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Painkiller_Jane_vs._Terminator) : 2

    1. a Series 800 Terminator
    2. a Series 1xxx Terminator
  - [Terminator 2: Infinity](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2%3a_Infinity) : 2

    1. [T-Infinity](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-Infinity_prototype)
    2. An other [Uncle Bob](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Uncle_Bob)
  - [Terminator: Revolution](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator%3a_Revolution) : 1

    1. [Dire Wolf](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Dire_Wolf)

Comment: Although I am of the opinion that 33% of the population in the SCC are terminators, 33% of resistance fighters sent into the past, and only 34% of the Earth's population are people living in their legitimate time.

Comment: In addition to these there may be some in the novels and comics.

Comment: I know, there is [at least one](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Uncle_Bob) in the comics. But this universe is largely unknown form me. And don't forget about Video-Games!!!

Comment: @JackBNimble One character from SCC was a collaborator from the future.  (Or just claimed by another Resistance member to be one; I forget)

Comment: @izkata [Charles Fischer](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Fischer)?

Comment: @DavRob60 Yep, that's him

Comment: Including comics could get messy. In *Robocop vs. Terminator*, I remember several waves of robots being sent back in time, although something about time ripples meant that some of them never happened.

Comment: @DavRob60, you should probably amend this answer to reflect the latest one.

Comment: @DavRob60 what about terminator: gensys (with the problem of how to include or not include the hybrid john connor)

Comment: Yeah, there's a few films and properties missing...

Comment: @Valorum Feel free to edit to improve this answer.

Comment: Terminator Dark Fate adds at least two, potentially many more (we dont know how many Sarah Conner dealt with after sms messages from her unknown source).

Answer (score 1):

In the movies a total of 5 machines were sent back in time by both sides. Two by the humans and three by Skynet. In the Sarah Conner Chronicles I can think of at least three more which were Cameron (John Conners bodyguard), Cromartie (yet another assassin) and Catherine Weaver.  Catherine Weaver  was in charge of safeguarding Skynet's research and development and to keep it safe from further terrorist attacks.

The sum of those I've mentioned is 8 terminators sent back in time. I think it's safe to assume that since so many had already been sent back that there could plausibly be many more that we don't even know about.

Comment: There's *at least* two more in TSCC - the one that gets sent back too far in time (back to 20s/30s Hollywood IIRC), and the one that gets sent back to acquire and guard stockpiles of Coltan that John gets locked in a warehouse with...

Comment: And Vick from the season 1 episode "Vick's Chip".